# 2 domains using the same host, but routed differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i have 2 domains (a.com and b.com) using the same application. However, I would need them to point to different routes.

a.com should use the action: /home/a_index

b.com should use the action: /home/b_index

What is the right way to handle this in rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.smallroomsoftware.com/articles/2007/2/10/rails-routing-based-on-hostname) and [this](http://feefighters.com/devblog/2009/01/21/hosting-multiple-domains-from-a-single-rails-app/) are both very useful articles describing one approach to running multiple domains from a single Rails application. Essentially the approach outlined in both articles allows you to route to different controllers for different domains using routing statements like the following:

```
map.connect '', :controller => 'blah', :action => 'blah', :conditions => {:domain => 'blah'}
```

This should allow you to achieve your goal.